'Use client' in onepage application in next.js
I have a one-page application in the src/app/page.js. I am confused about SSR and CSR. If I use use client, useEffect, and useState in this page with Framer Motion, will it impact the SEO of this page or not?

It should not impact SEO, because on full page load, the static parts of the page are rendered on the server.
reference here
